# Python threading error, can't run script

Tags: python, multithreading

I am not sure why, but I keep getting an error when I try to run one of my python programs. It is a simple script, as I was trying to understand how threading works.

This is the code I am using for the example:

```
import threading
import time

def myfunction():
    print("Start a thread")
    time.sleep(3)
    print ("End a thread")

threads = []

for i in range(5):
    #thread object
    thread = threading.Thread(target=myfunction)
    thread.start
    threads.append(thread)




for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

And this is the error I am receiving upon executing the script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blue.py", line 13, in <module>
    thread = threading.Thread(target=myfunction)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Thread'
Exception AttributeError: "'module' object has no attribute '_shutdown'" in <module 'threading' from '/home/user/Desktop/threading.pyc'> ignore
```

Thanks in advance to all of those who reply!

EDIT: So I am now running into a different error which is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "blue.py", line 21, in <module>
    thread.join()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 929, in join
    raise RuntimeError("cannot join thread before it is started")
RuntimeError: cannot join thread before it is started
```

Comment: Did you create your _own_ file named "threading.py"?  If so, rename it.

Comment: Yup, that was it haha. Thank you! However, now I am running in to another issue.

Comment: `thread.start` merely retrieves the `start` attribute of the `thread` object - you need to _call_ it instead:  `thread.start()`.

Comment: Again, that did the trick. Thank you so much!